# Gradle - Override dependency (exclude dependency) from included libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have some libraries I use in mutliple projects. My code in the library is compatible with more versions of the library (older and newer ones). BUT there are changes in the library that are not compatible with all build versions.

I have an older project that I currently don't want to update to the newest build tools version so for this single project I would like to forcefully override a the dependency.

Normally I do exclude dependencies from libraries like following:

```
compile ("com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.6.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

How can I exclude a dependency from local library project? I tried

```
compile project(':dialogs') {
    exclude group: 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs'
}
```

But this does not compile...

**EDIT**

Here's my dialog library:

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.4.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

And here's what I tried, but it does not work:

```
 compile(project(':dialogs')) {
    exclude group: 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs'
}
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1'
```

Problem: it compiles and runs, but I get `NoSuchMethod` exceptions. When I just comment out the 0.8.4.2 library lines and replace it with the 0.7.8.1 line (all in my library) everything works fine...

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No... It does not find methods if I do it like that, so I still comment out the code manually...

Answer (score 6):

Probably that should help:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/excluding-transitive-dependency-does-not-work-for-project-dependency/8719

> This is a syntax issue. The closure in which you are calling exclude is being interpreted as an argument to the project() method, which is incorrect. Should look like so:

```
compile(project(':baseproject')) {
    exclude group: 'com.miglayout'
}
```

See that **compile** wraps **project** with braces ()

Comment: You're right, didn't know I can use that syntax for local libraries as well. Works now, thank you very much

Comment: I just edited my question... I still have a problem. This does not work as expected... Any further ideas or tipps?

Comment: Could you provide log snippet? It's not clear for me who and when throws NoSuchMethod